# How to compare two CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, css

How to compare two CSS selectors on Javascript?

For example:

```
compare('.foo.bar', '.bar.foo')
```

returns `true`,

```
compare('.foo.bar', '.foo .bar')
```

returns `false`

Comment: What's the use-case for this function, what problem are you trying to solve? And how far did you get when you tried writing this yourself?

Comment: I tried with regex. It seems to be hard. Then, I thought of creating two dummy elements, with two very simple style rule and then compare the that rule

Comment: Your examples make sense to me — that all seems to be in order. Do you understand the difference the space makes?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Are you trying to create this `compare` method ? If so, do you want to know if a particular element does match these selectors ? Or if they are strictly the same ? An element could even have `foo.bar` has its `class` attribute, but then the selector would need to be `.foo\.bar`, do you want to parse it too ? What's the use case ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 '.foo.bar' is not the same as '.foo .bar'
```

Notice the space in `'.foo .bar'`

Eg:

```
<div class="foo"><p class="bar"></p></div>  The tag P matches '.foo .bar'

<div class="foo bar"><p class="bar"></p></div>  The tag DIV matches '.foo.bar'
```

For those seeking the compare function, you can use http://api.jquery.com/is/

```js
document.body.textContent = $('.foo.bar').is('.bar.foo')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo bar"></div>
```

Vanilla JS solution:

```js
document.body.textContent = compareSelector('.foo.bar', '.bar.foo');

function compareSelector (s1, s2) {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(s1);
  var b = document.querySelectorAll(s2);
  if (a.length !== b.length)
    return false;
  else {
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar"></div>
<p class="bar foo"></p>
```

Comment: Someone wants to close the question bcz it's too broad. WTF!?

Comment: There's no jQuery tag to this question.

Comment: You are right David, I would love to see a vanilla JS solution, plz post it!

Comment: vanilla `is(cssSelector)` is `element.matches(cssSelector)`... But since I don't get what's the question, this won't be an answer.

Comment: Ps : this doesn't compare two selectors, but just if one element does match both selectors : https://jsfiddle.net/56p20eob/

Comment: I added a vanilla solution to the answer. Great to know about element.matches!